# Using Hyperref in LyX - PDFLaTeX Hebrew

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, lyx, windows, hebrew

In the past year or so I have been using LyX in Hebrew with the Hebrew Article document class, with the PDFLaTeX format. Lately I found the Hyperref package, and with a single click all non-Hebrew Article documents now have clickable links.

When I try to do the same with a Hebrew Article document, I encounter a compiling error:

```
pdfTeX error (ext4): pdf_link_stack empty, \pdfendlink used without \pdfstart
```

It is possible to solve this issue and compile and document with clickable links, **without** switching over to XeTeX or other formats?

I am using Windows 7. Thanks in advance.

LyX file: http://www.filedropper.com/newfile1 and http://www.filedropper.com/newfile1_1

TeX text:

```
%% LyX 2.1.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1in,bmargin=1in,lmargin=1in,rmargin=1in,headheight=0.5in,headsep=0.5in,footskip=0.5in}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}
\usepackage{breakurl}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{theorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\R{משפט}}[section]
\AtBeginDocument{\make@lr\thetheorem}

% The following chunk fixes export with XeTeX.
% It is needed because polyglossia is used by default
% and \make@lr is only defined by babel.
\@ifundefined{make@lr}
{\def\make@lr#1{\begingroup
    \toks@=\expandafter{#1}%
    \edef\x{\endgroup
  \def\noexpand#1{\noexpand\@number{\the\toks@}}}%
  \x}}{\relax}

\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{tensind}
\tensordelimiter{?}
\usepackage{culmus}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{כותרת -- \L{Title}}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents{}

\newpage{}


\part{חלק -- \L{Part}}


\section{נושא -- \L{Section}}


\subsection{תת-נושא -- \L{Subsection}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: is it possible to make a small latex (rather than lyx) document that shows the problem, so we can debug, thanks.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think the question was updated according to your comment.

Comment: @FishyFod can you also post a .lyx minimal example? It is just a text file so you can copy/paste. Having the .lyx file corresponding to your .tex file will help a lot when figuring out if LyX is doing something wrong.

Comment: @scottkosty yes I need to install some fonts to test it seems but may try at weekend

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Added the LyX file

Comment: @scottkosty Added the LaTeX text.

Comment: @FishyFod Thanks for the example. I don't have the culmus package installed and last time I looked into it it was not straightforward on Ubuntu. Sorry for the off-topic question, but why do you not want to use XeTeX? I know nothing about Hebrew but I often try to help some users, so I'm interested in learning more about pdfTeX vs XeTeX for Hebrew users.

Comment: @scottkosty Thus far, I have only used pdfTeX, and switching over to XeTeX doesn't seem as straightforward as it should, and has a somewhat more difficult installation process (from what I can tell). Finding a reliable method where I can instruct others to install and set up LyX for Hebrew isn't so simple as it is, so I'm trying to avoid making the instructions even more convoluted. However, if all else fails, I might try switching over to XeTeX.

Comment: @FishyFod Thanks for the explanation. From what I've read, using XeTeX might actually make things easier for you (not more complicated). For example, I can easily compile all the LyX Hebrew help documents with XeTeX using the David CLM fonts (let me know if you want help on this). Installation of XeTeX is trivial and you actually probably already have XeTeX installed (MikTeX takes care of this for you). But this is off-topic. on-topic: once you or David figures out a solution to the LaTeX part of the pdfTeX issue, ping me if you need help converting a LaTeX solution into a LyX solution.

Comment: @scottkosty It would be extremely helpful if you could provide a link containing instructions on installing XeTeX with Hebrew support. If this worked for you with Ubuntu, then maybe a similar method would also work for Mac, which would make the program more accessible to others. I am still interested if there's a solution using pdfTeX, since all of my previous documents use it.

Comment: @FishyFod Are you sure it doesn't work already? On Ubuntu when I install pdfTeX XeTeX is automatically installed. In LyX if you start a *new* document and type "hello" and then click on the button that says "View other Formats" is there an entry that you can select that says "View PDF (XeTeX)" ?

Comment: @FishyFod ping. See my above questions.

Comment: @scottkosty I tried XeTeX, but it interferes with the Theorem packages in Hebrew, so it's unusable for me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @FishyFod I see. Sorry to hear that. I hope you find something that works.